# Should context.SaveChanges() be called after adding all objects to context?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am new to EF 4.1, i am trying to add list of object to sql table using EF and DB first approach.

1) Should i be calling context.SaveChanges() inside for loop after AddObject(Trans) or its okay to call it outside the loop?

2) Also, would all transactions be roll back in case there is an error? 
I have read the Entity Framework already supports native database transactions, If any dirty ObjectStateEntry object cannot be persisted, then ObjectContext.SaveChanges will roll back the transaction and throw an exception.

3) What else can be done to increase the performance? I will be inserting around 1200 records in one go.

```
try
{
    using (TransactionModel context = new TransactionModel())
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in lstUnAllocatedTransaction)
            {
                Transaction Trans = new Transaction();

                Trans.Amount = item.Amount;
                Trans.Date = Datetime.Now;
                Trans.DateAllocated = null;

                context.Transactions.AddObject(Trans);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
}
```

Comment: So the `Transaction` in your example is a business object, not a DB transaction?

Comment: There is allways bulk operations that do not supported by EF unfortunately.

Comment: Transaction is an entity, auto generated class by EF (custom tool)

Comment: I did look into bulk operation option but not sure if i would notice any difference when adding up to 1.2k or 1.4k rows in one go. I would need to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Should i be calling context.SaveChanges() inside for loop after AddObject(Trans) or its okay to call it outside the loop?

It's okay (and preferable) to call outside the loop if it's okay that the whole add operations are one transaction. If you need one transaction per item, then obviously you need to call it inside the loop.

> 2) Also, would all transactions be roll back in case there is an error? I have read the Entity Framework already supports native database transactions, If any dirty ObjectStateEntry object cannot be persisted, then ObjectContext.SaveChanges will roll back the transaction and throw an exception.

Only the last transaction will be rolled back. That's why 1) makes a difference. If you want to insert all-or-none then you need to add all and then call `SaveChanges` once.

> 3) What else can be done to increase the performance? I will be inserting around 1200 records in one go.

You could call `AddRange` instead of `Add`, otherwise I never had problems with a small number of records. If you think it's too slow, look into bulk inserts. There is nothing build into EF to do that, you will need an extension.

Comment: Is AddRange available in EF 4.1 ?

Comment: @user1263981 Oh wow, 4.1 is ancient... I don't know. Do you have problems with it?

Comment: can't use higher version as current application is on version 4.1.